# xCode initialize static std::string

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, stl, stdstring

Please check this picture:
[image]
Why in the world the base64_chars is shown as empty in Debugger window and it is actually empty, cause the char_array4 is getting filled with `\xff` instead of correct indexes. 
Can someone tell me what is wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Are you compiling in Debug or Release mode?  It is very common for the debugger to return incorrect data when debugging optimized code in a Release build.

Comment: When is the call to `FromBase64String` taking place?  Is it taking place during dynamic initialization of static variables?

Comment: that's in Debug mode.
is happening during viewDidLoad event when I use a member variable of the UIView.